# Does the logback configuration debug attribute work on logback-spring.xml file?

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.3 and in my `logback-spring.xml` I set `<configuration debug="true">` but no status message is printed to console.

My `logback-spring.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
  <springProfile name="default">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
    <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
  </springProfile>
  <springProfile name="!default">
    <appender name="JSON_CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
      <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <includeTags>false</includeTags>
      </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="JSON_CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
  </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

I got the configuration from Logback [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#dumpingStatusData).

Does this configuration only work on `logback.xml` file?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration is working properly, it was my fault, I analyzed the log carefully and the messages were printed.